# Poor's man way to debug font-lock matcher functions?

Tags: debugging, font-lock, match-data

I was [told on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/6cs5fb/my_fontlock_rule_made_with_code_does_not_to_work/) that font-lock-studio will help me debug a matcher I was working on, however, I find myself with one more problem than before as I need to learn edebug and also grasp how to debug my font-lock keywords with font-lock-studio.

Thus, I thought maybe setting up something like *behavioral tests* on the matcher function to help me with the debugging and testing of the matcher itself as I don't exactly know what am I doing (doing right or wrong, to be honest).

At some point, the matcher use `set-match-data` for the resulting matches, I was wondering if there was a way to get that data in order to compare it with the results I'm looking (`match-data` is the way to go? Because I eval it after executing manually the matcher function and the values I see makes no sense to me), and also a way to setup a test for the matcher function that can be run at a command.

Comment: Some parts of your question are not clear, to me. Have you read the doc about `font-lock-keywords`, to understand the possible formats? *Have you read the doc about `match-data`?* (If not, that's probably the place to start.) Have you looked at some examples that use font-lock? And please consider showing **what you have tried**, stating what the result was, and what you expected to see instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `font-lock-studio` to visualize the match data. If you step the matcher function using, say space, the parts of the source buffer that corresponds to the match data is highlighted. The different matches are highlighted in different colors.

If you would like to call your function directly, you can call `match-data` to get a list that represents the matches. In your case, it should contains eight elements, as in `(BEG0 END0 BEG1 END1 etc.)`.

Edebug isn't hard. You can enable it by evaluating the function using `C-u M-C-x` and then call it. Execution will stop at the beginning of the function and you can single step though it using space. I would start with the simpler functions, making sure `amzn-font-lock-skip-whitespace-etc` work as intended (the regexp in `looking-at` looks suspicious).

If you want to write regression tests, you can use the built-in `ert` package.

To write regression tests for font-lock packages you can use the package [faceup](https://github.com/Lindydancer/faceup).

Comment: Nothing is highlighted, that's the issue. Other keywords made of regex are, but not the matcher.

Comment: I accepted the answer because it cover many aspects of my question and stuff that aren't asked on it, which is good.

Comment: @shackra, I can try to figure out the problem, can you post a link to the code and an example sourest file to highlight.

Comment: First, thank you very much! Second, the link to the [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/6cs5fb/my_fontlock_rule_made_with_code_does_not_to_work/) I linked in the question was updated with the things you need, please let me know on Reddit or edit your answer and tell me what you were able to find!

Comment: I just answered the reddit post.